# Underline letter in a button

Tags: c#, winforms, button

In my form, I have four buttons that do different tasks. The
button.Text field is set as &Next Project, so the N will be underlined.
In the preview of the form, it shows up with the N underlined. Yet
when I run my program, the text shows up with no underlining.

Comment: press alt and it will be

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Those keyshortcuts are only working in combination with the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-Key, and therefor only show up if it is pressed.

Also there [seem to be two ways](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/36672-Enable-mnemonics-underline-winform.aspx) to always show the Mnemonics:

1. Change the Windows Desktop/Theme Settings:

   - Right Click Desktop -> Properties
   - Got to the Appereance Tab -> Effects
   - Uncheck "Hide Underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the ALT Key"
2. Change the System-Parameters via an API-Call.

Comment: Can it be set automatically..?