# Why does the WPF IsCancel functionality trigger on the 'A' Key

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple window with an OK and a Cancel Button. I set the IsCancel property on the Cancel button to true. Simple enough. Now when I press the 'ESC' key the button click event fires. But by exident I found out that this also fires when I press the 'A' key. I then checked every other key on my keyboard but 'ESC' and 'A' where the only keys triggering this.

Is there any explanation on why this is happening? I would guess .NET 4.0 bug but maybe there is an actual reason for this.

I was also using Windows 8.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. Could you provide a sscce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have a lot to go on, but is it possible that the 'a' in cancel is underlined?  Perhaps there is a keyboard shortcut in play on that button.

When you open your window, try pressing the 'ALT' key to see if the 'a' gets underlined.

See this for some more details:
[Underline letter in a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176869/underline-letter-in-a-button)

Comment: Great guess. That is almost exactly what’s happening. When I press ALT the C from Cancel gets underlined. But this application also runs in German. So when I use the German frontend Cancel is replaced with "Abbrechen" where the A gets underlined. So A closes the window in the German frontend, while C closes it in the English one. The only question remaining is why this is working without pressing ALT first. Isn't that how it is supposed to work?

Comment: I had to google this one, but here is an answer:  "This is the way mnemonics are supposed to work, and the behaviour is the same in windows forms. If the focus is on an element that doesn't actually accept keystrokes itself (textboxes do, buttons don't) the alt key is optional when triggering a mnemonic on another control on the window."  Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5507c089-9b81-4a9c-b9fb-972a42335ddb/wpf-access-keys-why-do-they-work-without-the-alt-key?forum=wpf